# Given an m * n grid, each edge must be colored. However, there are constraints

Tags: python, algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization, combinatorics

Given an m * n grid, each edge must be colored. However, there are 2 constraints:

1. Entire grid must use only 3 unique colors
2. Each square in the grid must be colored using exactly 2 colors (2 edges per color)

Is there a way to find a non polynomial python code to the number of possible solutions for the given problem?

I get the O(3 ^ (m * n)) solution using DFS. but that's not a viable one. Looking for a faster approach (maybe using DP or graph?).

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/ might be a better community for this.

Answer (score 2):

O(1) solution for r rows and k columns:

```
18 * 6^(k-1) * 6^(r-1) * 2^( (k-1) * (r-1) )
```

Explanation:

Start with the top-left cell. There are 3 colors you can use for the top edge, and 3 places for the matching-color edge for a total of 9, then 2 more colors to choose from for the other pair of edges for a final total of 18.

Next, place an adjacent cell in the same row. The left edge has a color; there are 3 places for the matching color and 2 other colors for a total of 6 options. Each other cell in this row has 6 options, so if the top row has k cells, those cells can be colored in 18 * 6 ^ (k-1) ways.

Moving on to the next row, the difference is that now we have cells above us colored. The top cell of the second row has 6 options (same logic as the 2nd+ cells in the first row). After that, we have both the top and left cells colored. If they're both the same, then there are 2 choices (the other colors). If they're different, then there are also 2 choices (colors are fixed, but there are 2 orientations). Therefore, for rows 2+, each cell after the first has 2 possibilities.

Okay, so putting it all together, let's say we have r rows and k columns, 3 colors, and the rules you stated in your question.

Then the number of solutions is:

18 * 6^(k-1) * 6^(r-1) * 2^((k-1)*(r-1))

Ruby code and sample counts:

```
def f(r, k)
  return 18 * 6 **(k-1) * 6 ** (r-1) * 2 **((k-1)*(r-1))
end
```

Samples for (r, k) rows and columns:

```
(1, 1): 18
(1, 2): 108
(1, 3): 648
(1, 4): 3888
(1, 5): 23328
(2, 2): 1296
(2, 3): 15552
(2, 4): 186624
(2, 5): 2239488
(3, 3): 373248
(3, 4): 8957952
(3, 5): 214990848
(4, 4): 429981696
(4, 5): 20639121408
(5, 5): 1981355655168
```

Comment: To be clear, the rows and columns above are referring to the squares, so r=k=1 is a single square with 4 edges. My solutions agree with Erwin Kalvelagen, but his dimensions refer to edges not squares so his 4x4 grid is 3x3 squares or r=k=3 in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using a mixed integer programming (mip) model and the solution pool, for a 4x4 grid I see:

```
--- Cplex Time: 5.94sec (det. 4774.48 ticks)
--- Dumping 373248 solutions from the solution pool...
```

For a 4x5 grid:

```
--- Cplex Time: 440.67sec (det. 167328.64 ticks)
--- Dumping 8957952 solutions from the solution pool...
```

This is quickly growing to very large numbers. I am not sure if this is very interesting. The obvious follow-up question: what are you going to do with these 8,957,952 solutions?